# Install Ubuntu on USB

Tags: usb

I wish to install ubuntu to my usb without partitioning or touching the current setup on my computer.

Comment: You need two USB, one to install from and one to install to. Or you can just extract ISO to the one and use it as a live installer. You can add persistence which lets you save some data, but not update Ubuntu system files as installer says as installer of version it is. If installing from one to another only use Something Else and be sure to install grub2 to sdb or whatever flash drive is. Best not to post email as forums are regularly scanned, and you will get spam.  Go Illini. '69 http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to just have an Ubuntu recovery boot stick (ie: you don't plan to actually customise a genuine Ubuntu installation and just use it for administering Windows boxes when they break), then I highly recommend downloading the [Rufus tool for Windows](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) which will allow you to turn almost any ISO into a bootable USB stick.

If you wish to have a physically installed version of Ubuntu where the USB stick is a stand-in for a hard-drive, then as already mentioned, you will need two sticks - one to install from and the other to install to.

Neither of these paths will make any changes to your Windows installation.